# WPF: listview display recently added items on top instead of bottom

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a collection bind to a listview. This collection gets items added every 4-5 seconds and new items will automatically be added in bottom of the listview. So if you gonna see newest items then you need to scroll down to the bottom.

My question is:
is it possible to like reverse the listview so the new newest items are on top and oldest items in bottom ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you just want to display the items the other way around: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9153296/276648

Comment: Good question. It is extremely annoying if you need to manually scroll often to get the newly added items in view. Ideally you 'd use a method to get the listview scroll automatically to the end, but that is NOT easy, so inserting at the top is THE solution.

Comment: @Roland: it is easy to get scrolled to the recently added item at the end. I have explained in my answer below. I would say, it as the best option for this question considering the performance overhead associated with frequent sorting/shifting elements in listview,

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `Insert` instead of `Add` :

```
collection.Insert(0, newItem);
```

Note that it's slower than `Add` since it has to shift all items by 1 position. It might be an issue if the list is very big.

Comment: Ahh yes, duh why didn't I think of that.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent performance issues by reversing the listview instead of the collection ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you already voted the other answer as accepted, as they pointed out, while that is a simple, one-line solution, that does a lot of shifting and such which can affect performance.

IMHO, a better, correct way to do this would be to use sorting.  It's easy to get the default view of a collection, then apply sorting to it, or just use a CollectionViewSource and apply sorting there.  Of course that means you have to have a field to sort on, but that could be as simple as adding an index property if you don't already have a time-stamp or something similar.

Let me know if you want a code example here and I'll provide one.

Comment: Why would you think that sorting with Add() is faster than shifting with Insert(0)?

Comment: Just a purist approach.  Display order is a function of the UI and not a function of storage order.  Also, what if you wanted to work on the model without a UI (batch processing, bulk inserts, scripting, etc.)? You'd still take the hit of shifting the data on every single insert. With a sort on the view, it wouldn't be affected at all without a UI, and with a UI, you could defer the sort until after all inserts are done.  Again, the insert will work, and if that's all you're doing, then it's fine. But it's just not a recommended design. However there are always exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1) Use CollectionChange event to capture any item-change in the list.
Then sort the list in descending order and then render.

```
// subscribe to CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection
_recordingsHidden.CollectionChanged += RecordingsHiddenOnCollectionChanged;
private void RecordingsHiddenOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
{
        var view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvCallHistory.ItemsSource);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("StartTime", ListSortDirection.Descending));
}
```

Here 'lvCallHistory' is my list view and sorting is done based on 'StartTime'.
This approach is effective only if the list contains less items. Because sorting is a costly operation and if you update the list frequently, then it might affect the performance of the application. The user may experience 2-3 seconds lag each time the view is rendered.

2) Avoid sorting: Every time you update the list, point the scroll bar to the last added item. (Pros: Very effective and no performance issue. Cons: Items still added to the end of list, even though scroll bar takes you to the new item whenever a new entry comes.)

```
lvCallHistory.SelectedItem = <your_collection>.Last();
lvCallHistory.ScrollIntoView(lvCallHistory.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score -1):

Set sorting order to descending and use add items

```
this.listView1.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;

listView1.Items.Add( listviewitem);
```

or remove sorting and insert item

```
listView1.Items.Insert(0, listviewitem);
```

either of them will work..

Comment: Your example is for WinForms.  The OP specified WPF.