# Present ListBox Items Bottom-to-Top

Tags: wpf, layout, listbox

I've searched for quite a while trying to find an answer to this without any results.

The default WPF Listbox adds items aligned at the top, and additional items below it. I'd like a listbox which presents the items in the opposite direction, so it adds items aligned to the bottom.

Example:
[image]

I'm sure there must be a simpler way that I've overlooked to do this without rewriting it all, but Google doesn't seem to have the answer for this one and I'm stumped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change the `ItemsPanel`'s layout:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

This does what your image seems to imply, with the first item added still on top. If you want to reverse the order as well that would be a different issue.

Comment: Thanks the quick reply, this works and I can reverse the order myself.