# C# WPF ListBox Chat

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, chat

I'm working on C# WPF Chat application. I want it to look like Skype chat, so last added item is touching the bottom of ListBox.

Screenshot:

[image]

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxMain" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding User}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text=": " FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Width="225" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: What is the question here? Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present ListBox Items Bottom-to-Top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153296/present-listbox-items-bottom-to-top)

Comment: how to do that  last added item is touching the bottom of ListBox

Comment: i tried <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>, but it doesnt work.

Comment: It works. Where did you put it? Post the updated XAML for your ListBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the internal `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ListBox`... try this:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxMain" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding User}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text=": " FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Width="225" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```