# Put the last item in the listview at the top of the listview in C#

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first time posting here at stackoverflow, so here is my question. I want my code to show the newly entered data in the database at the top of the listview. Thank you in advance for answering !

Here's my code for insert data:

```
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblInfo(FirstName,LastName,Summary,ContactNumber) values('" + txt_fn.Text + "','" + txt_ln.Text + "','" + txt_summary.Text + "','" + txt_contact.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data saved!", "Call Logger System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            conn.Close();
```

Here's my code for showing the data in the database using listview

```
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblInfo";
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["FirstName"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(reader["LastName"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(reader["ContactNumber"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(reader["Summary"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: listview display recently added items on top instead of bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723373/wpf-listview-display-recently-added-items-on-top-instead-of-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle it would be to have an Id column that was created as `IDENTITY(1,1)`  Then add an `ORDER BY Id DESC` to your query to sort by the most recent at the top.

Comment: Ahhh I see that logic, didn't think of that though. Thank you for answering !